# Optimizing code and SQL query for better performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, wcf, memory-leaks, query-optimization

On a web application with high traffic, SQL Server Express has been using around 715-720 MB of server memory. Up to what I know, Express has 1GB of usable memory by default.

Question: is 715-720 MB (70% of SQL Server Express usable memory limit) considered a high memory usage?

In case the above memory usage was considered high, I would like to know if I can optimize the below code and queries for better performance and avoid memory leaks if they exist.

The below function is a WCF Web Service that returns JSON:

```
Public Function HomeNews() As List(Of HomeSectionsList) Implements IService.HomeNews
    Dim daQuery As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dtSections = New DataTable
    Try
        Using myconnection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString)
            myconnection.Open()                
            MyCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP(8) * FROM containers", myconnection)
            daQuery = New SqlDataAdapter(MyCommand)
            daQuery.Fill(dtSections)                
        End Using

       Dim lstHomeSections As New List(Of HomeSectionsList)()

        If dtSections.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each mySectionRow As DataRow In dtSections.Rows
                Dim lstArticles As New List(Of ArticleList)() 
                Using myconnection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString)
                    MyCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP (10) a.*, (SELECT image FROM TABLE_X WHERE id=1) AS ads_image, (SELECT link FROM TABLE_X WHERE id=1) AS ads_link FROM articles a WHERE a.containerid=" & mySectionRow.Item("id") & " ORDER BY a.publish_date DESC", myconnection)

                    lstHomeSections.Add(New HomeSectionsList With {
                                        .id = mySectionRow.Item("id"),
                                        .title = mySectionRow.Item("title"),
                                        .articles = CreateArticleList(MyCommand)})
                End Using                   
            Next
        End If
        Return lstHomeSections
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim lstHomeSections As New List(Of HomeSectionsList)()
        Return lstHomeSections
    End Try
End Function

Public Function CreateArticleList(myCustomSQLCommand As SqlCommand) As List(Of ArticleList)
    Dim dtSelected As DataTable
    Dim daQuery As SqlDataAdapter
    Try
        Using myconnection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString)
            myconnection.Open()
            daQuery = New SqlDataAdapter(myCustomSQLCommand)
            dtSelected = New DataTable
            daQuery.Fill(dtSelected)
        End Using

        Dim lstArticles As New List(Of ArticleList)()
        If dtSelected.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each myArticleRow As DataRow In dtSelected.Rows
                lstArticles.Add(New ArticleList() With {
                                .id = myArticleRow.Item("id"),
                                .title = myArticleRow.Item("title"),
                                .image = myArticleRow.Item("image"),
                                .ad = CreateAdsList()                                   
                    })
            Next
        End If
        Return lstArticles
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim lstArticles As New List(Of ArticleList)()
        Return lstArticles
    End Try
End Function

Public Function CreateAdsList() As List(Of AdsList)
    Dim daQuery As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim lstAds As New List(Of AdsList)()
    Dim dtAds = New DataTable
    Try
        Using myconnection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString)
            myconnection.Open()
            MyCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT a.image, a.link FROM ads a WHERE id=1", myconnection)
            daQuery = New SqlDataAdapter(MyCommand)
            daQuery.Fill(dtAds)
        End Using

        If dtAds.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each myrow As DataRow In dtAds.Rows                    
                lstAds.Add(New AdsList() With {
                           .image = myrow.Item("image"),
                           .link = myrow.Item("link")
                           })
            Next
        End If
        Return lstAds
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return lstAds
    End Try
End Function
```

Below is sample of the returned JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Container title", 
        "articles": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Title 1",
                "ad": [
                    {
                        "image": "path-to-image/image.png",
                        "link": "http://example.com"                    
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Title 2",
                "ad": [
                    {
                        "image": "path-to-image/image.png",
                        "link": "http://example.com"                    
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

- Does those queries result in any memory leakage?
- Does those nested `USING` statments result in any latency?

How can I better optimize this piece of code knowing that each function calls the other function?

Comment: SQL Server uses memory to improve performance by caching data. High utilization does not necessarily indicate a query performance problem. You should parameterized queries instead of building with string concatenation.

Comment: What happens if the SQL server reached the max limit then? Would it consume the free memory on the server or would I experience a timeout connection or deadlock? Sure, I'm using parametrized queries when then input is from the user @DanGuzman

Comment: SQL will honor the max memory setting and not continue to acquire memory. Timeouts and deadlocks are not directly related to memory. Parameterized queries have [benefits in addition to security](https://www.dbdelta.com/help-stop-sql-injection-madness/).

Comment: Like Dan already said, it's normal on productive servers for SQL to use all the memory allocated. If you want to prevent SQL Server paging to disk, you can enable [Lock Pages in Memory Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-the-lock-pages-in-memory-option-windows?view=sql-server-2017)